# How to override print for javascript object

Tags: javascript

```
function SomeObject() {
  this.attribute = 'something'
}

SomeObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.attribute
}

var so = new SomeObject()
console.log(so)
```

You will see

`{ attribute: 'something' }`

Is it possible to override what gets printed.

For example:
print `'something'` (instead of `{attribute: 'something'}`)

Note: This is node.js

Comment: Look into `toString` and `valueOf`.

Comment: I have already overriden toString but when I do console.log it is still not using toString

Comment: Would it be possible for you to just write a function to log stuff the way you want, and just call that function with your objects?

Comment: Why does `console.log()` matter? What behavior do you need in your application? If it's just a `console.log()` issue, then call `.toString()` explicitly.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/LoLvx8aj/

Comment: `.toString()` is called whenever the object is converted into a string. `console.log()` doesn't do that, but whatever the actual use case is it should work. You can do `console.log(''+so)` if you want to check if `.toString()` is working.

Comment: I came from rails development where it was easy to override stuff. I can definitely just call toString explicitly although I am curious if there is a solution to avoid that

Comment: `console.log("%s", so)`